# How do i hide date section from my post page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi everyone i want to hide date from my AD section (http://prntscr.com/lgsb8), i tried few CSS codes with inspect element but they seems to be not working.

Any one please check and provide me correct CSS code to hide or remove this from page.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nth-child to achieve this.

```
.short-features div:nth-child(3){
    display: none;
}
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) you have some information about it, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for code, i added the code you provided me in my custom css. but this code seems to be not working. :(

Comment: Can you provide the css you are using?

Comment: using this css:
.short-features:nth-child(2){
  display: none;
}

screenshot: http://prntscr.com/lgsk5f

Comment: Sorry, I mean your custom css.

Comment: Full custom css code: .short-history li:first-child {
    display: none;
}

.ad-archive-desc .last-updated {
    display: none;
}

.short-features:nth-child(2){
  display: none;
}

Comment: Try this,   .short-features div:nth-child(3){display: none;}

Comment: I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the date display in the theme editor by commenting out this code in your template:

```
<?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at  <?phpthe_time() ?>
```

do this:

```
<!--<?phpthe_time('F  j, Y'); ?> at <?phpthe_time() ?>-->
```

these  will leave the code intact in case you ever want to put the date back in. As long as the code is commented out the date will not appear on the live page.